# How to install WordPress without using the /wp-admin/install.php script?

Tags: wordpress, installation, automation

I am trying to create a system that will install WordPress without any browser interaction like-

- I will create a database
- I will upload/create `WordPress` required `database` tables manually
  (**I have installed a `WordPress` normally then collect the `database` tables and imported them into database**).
- I will create a `wp-config.php` manually and fill it with necessary
  information what it requires(`database name,username,password,Authentication Unique Keys` etc).

---

Now problem is after done this process I ended up on here - 
It redirects me on `domain.com/wp-admin/install.php`.

**How to achieve install `WordPress` without any interaction from user,completely automatically?**

> Note: I am actually trying to install WordPress on behalf of my users
>   when they would register on  my platform it will install a WordPress
>   on their wildcard subdomain automatically which I don't want to let them touch
>   any part of WordPress installation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `wp` command](https://wp-cli.org/) to perform an installation of WordPress.

Use the command `wp core download` to download the latest version of WordPress, and `wp core install` or `wp core multisite-install` to install WordPress using the name, email and database credentials you supply.

See the [documentation for `wp core`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/) for more details.